# Is there a sans serif dagger symbol?

Tags: beamer, symbols, affiliation

I am looking for a sans-serif equivalent to `\dag` and `\ddag`, which is typeset in serifs even when sans serif is used throughout the document.

I use symbols (like `\dag` and `\ddag`) to display the affiliation of the authors of a `beamer` slideshow with two institutions, so I am also interested in functional equivalents, which are not daggers (but not simply superscripts either).

Comment: Wouldn't a sans-serif dagger just be a cross?

Comment: Maybe `\textdied` from `textcomp`.

Comment: See `texdoc memoir` page 237 for a list of the symbols frequently used in such cases.

Comment: @AndrewCashner, the dagger symbol has a double dagger equivalent and is not identical to the cross symbol (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dagger_(typography))

Comment: dagger is U+2020  (†) and so you just need a sans font that covers this range (as your browser is probably using to show this comment)

Comment: I am using Computer Modern (sans), which I would expect to cover this symbol, but it apparently does not.
@Sigur, \textdied produces a christian cross (U+271D), not a dagger (U+2020).

Comment: @Constantin cm fonts only have 127 characters they are not even close to unicode range

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. What's a similar-looking unicode font?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you expect a “sans serif dagger” would be.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\newcommand{\sfdagger}{{\sffamily\textdagger}}
\newcommand{\sfdaggerdbl}{{\sffamily\textdaggerdbl}}

\begin{document}
A\sfdagger A\textdagger

A\sfdaggerdbl A\textdaggerdbl
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, if the text is already sans serif, there's no need to use a special command. The key is loading `textcomp`, so `\textdagger` and `\textdaggerdbl` will be taken from a TS1 encoded font and not from the math font as it happens when `textcomp` is not loaded.

Comment: Maybe better to show next to sans-serif text?

Comment: @AndrewCashner If the text is sans serif, also the daggers will be with the normal command, provided `textcomp` is loaded.

Comment: Thanks. Again I wish there was better documentation for `textcomp`.

Comment: It turns out when I load `textcomp`, I obtain the dagger in the upper left when using `\dag` and `\ddag`, which performs very nicely with sans-serif text.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, here is a Unicode solution.
It uses Latin Modern, which is based on Computer Modern but extends into the Unicode range.
You can access this range by using the `fontspec` package and compiling with `lualatex` or `xelatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
Unicode dagger\dag \char"2020 % these are the same glyph
\end{document}
```

I don't know if this is the specific symbol you want, but the `\char` command allows you to use any Unicode symbol supported by the font. Other fonts have even wider Unicode ranges.